Is there a name for the uncountable-chain-with-countable-supremum paradox?
[In this post, the power set of a set $S$ is denoted $\mathcal{P}(S)$. A "chain in $\mathcal{P}(S)$" is a collection of subsets of $S$ that is totally ordered by inclusion.]
An obvious fact about finite sets is:

For any finite set $S$, the largest possible cardinality of a chain in $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is $|S|+1$.

The intuition is clear:

In a given chain, the increment between one member of the chain and another member of the chain must have cardinality at least $1$;
but the number of available members of $S$ that can be used to construct such an increment is no more than $|S|$ itself;
and so it is impossible to construct any chain longer than what you'd get by starting with the empty set, and then adding one member of $S$ at a time until you reach the whole of $S$.

What is counterintuitive is that this fails to extend to infinite sets:

For any countably infinite set $S$, there exists an uncountably infinite chain in $\mathcal{P}(S)$.

(Proof: With $S=\mathbb{Q}$, Dedekind's construction of $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is precisely an example of such a chain.)
Is there a name for this paradox?

It's not a paradox, why would it be paradoxical?

@AsafKaragila I guess the intuition goes along "each new element of the chain must be richer by at least one distinct element of the original set, so we can produce at most as many chain elements as there are in the original set". Finding out that cardinality can arise from going "inside" rather than going "forwards" (e.g. in total orders) might feel paradoxical.

@AsafKaragila Well, to me it feels a bit counterintuitive that a continuum-indexed strictly monotone growth is able to grow to a merely-countable size. To my mind, a "paradox" means something that feels like it involves two simultaneous things being "at odds" with each other: in this case, the continuum-indexed growth feels intuitively at odds with the countable end-result. Of course, when one builds up a sufficiently clear mental picture of what is going on, the counterintuitiveness can start to dissipate, like it does for the Paradox of Hilbert's Hotel, or the Ross-Littlewood Paradox.

I don't know if there's a name for it, but this is closely related to question B4 on the 1989 William Lowell Putnam Examination, discussed at https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/putn89.html and "The William Lowell Putnam
Mathematical Competition 1985–2000 Problems, Solutions, and Commentary"

If every little thing had a paradox named after it, we'd call this paradox theory. Plenty of results, fundamental results, seem surprising at first.
